# Editing the scope of an API URL

Tags: php, api, url, foreach

Hello everyone I need a bit of help editing a API scope based on the sites url so if i have foo.com/?Wab_id=15 it will edit the API scope to

```
?scope=accepted&view=films&wab_id=15
```

I was thinking i could have something like

```
$ApiData = file_get_contents('http://foo.com/api/?scope=accepted&view=films/&wab_id=$id');
```

and then using Get to retrieve the id thats being passed into the url to edit the url of the API. i also tried looping though the entire json and then calling the a key inside of the array but also didn't get much luck my code is below

```
    $ApiData = file_get_contents('http://foo.com/api/?scope=accepted&view=films');
$obj = json_decode($ApiData, true);
$data = $obj;
//here you load $data with whatever you want.
$id = $_GET['id'];
foreach ($data[$id] as $key=>$value){
echo "$key -> $value<br>";
}
?>
```

but this returns a error of

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

ive also tried looping through the Muti array with a foreach inside of a foreach and have displayed the values the code and results are below

```
$obj = json_decode($ApiData, true);
$data = $obj;
//here you load $data with whatever you want.

foreach ( $data as $film ){
  foreach ( $film as $key=>$val ){
    echo "$key -> $val<br>";
  }
}
```

results

```
uid -> 95
wab_id -> 95
title -> La Batalla de los Invisibles
title_en -> Battle of the Invisibles
syn_sm ->
syn_med -> 
syn_lg -> 
form -> 
genre -> 
language -> 
subtitle_lang -> 
year -> 
runtime -> 
place_sub_city -> 
place_sub_state -> 
place_sub_country -> 
place_film_country -> Mexico
place_dir_city -> 
place_dir_state -> 
place_dir_country -> 
accepted -> 1
festival_year -> 2014
trailer -> 
links ->
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking but for sure looping int is not a good idea. Moreover it's better to use CURL instead of file_get_contents() to retrive website content

Comment: That would be because you wouldn't have $data[95]` set.

Comment: Are you passing `wab_id`, `Wab_id`, or `id` to your server where you will access with `$_GET`? Because its not clear under which key you are passing it to yourself and if you are using the correct one - which may be the issue you are having right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment:

> Are you passing wab_id, Wab_id, or id to your server where you will access with $_GET? Because its not clear under which key you are passing it to yourself and if you are using the correct one - which may be the issue you are having right now.

After you have that squared away manipulating the API params should be a simple affair:

```
$api = "http://foo.com/api/";
$params = array(
   'scope' => 'accepted',
   'view' => 'films',
);

// you need to match the key you are using here to what you are passing
// to your URL
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $params['wab_id'] = $_GET['id'];
}

$url = $api . '?' . http_build_query($params);
```

Now for the last part, you really should use `cURL`, `Http`... or really any thing other than `file_get_contents` because it doesnt really give you a very good way to handle errors you may come across. I'll give you a quick example using `cURL`:

```
$client = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($client, array(
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRASNFER => true,
   CURLOPT_URL => $url // the one we dynmically built above
));

$responseText = curl_exec($client);

if ($responseText !== false) {
   $responseInfo = curl_getinfo($client);

   if ($responseInfo['http_code'] === 200) {
       // http status ok - you may need to take action based 
       // on other http status codes but im not going to delve into that here.

       $data = json_decode($responseText, true);
       print_r($data);

    } else {
      printf('Error accessing data: HTTP Status %s', $responseInfo['http_code'];
    }
} else {
  printf('Error: (%s) %s', curl_errno($client), curl_error($client));
}

curl_close($client);
```

Comment: `client = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($client, array(
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRASNFER => true,
   CURLOPT_URL => $url
));` returns an error of  `curl_setopt_array(): Array keys must be CURLOPT constants or equivalent integer values in /home/jewellsc/public_html/handler.php on line 20
Error: (3) No URL set!` and this is probably and easy fix but ive never worked with curl unless it was for laravel